# Problem when displaying hex bytes in Bless

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, text-editor

I've tried Bless. It worked fast and well. But it has a prolem. It does not display all the hex byte, like the picture below. I don't know how to fix this, could anyone help me?
[image]

I'm using lubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu32 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:28 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I noticed when your Hex was blank your ASCII was "." Could it be the file you are looking at has lots of Hex and ASCII 0's? Or could there be an option in your menu's to blank out non-printable characters? Sorry don't know Bless just brainstorming. As far as your question just google Hex Editors for Linux and there will be lots of choices. And just to cheer you up you never had to learn EBCIDIC.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you, I think I will choose GHex instead.

Comment: You are most welcome. GHex sounds like a good choice. Although there is no money back guarantee it costs nothing which is the same price of the next one you try :)